# Mathematica, ML and TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensors

I am currently studying a specialization on Coursera in Machine Learning and am investigating various tools to help me out with the maths and with visualisations and so on.

Although I have many decades experience of development and am very handsome, I haven't done any formal maths study since my early 20s. So I want to take the edge off.

As a first excursion, I would like to be able to plot the results of predictions on my TensorFlow models against the training data, in a similar way `tfvis` library that comes along with `tensorflow.js`; but perhaps allowing me to tweak the layers, units and so on of my regressor model and see the effect in real time.

Am I dreaming here? Can Mathematica help me with that? If not, can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: There are dedicated tools for that (e.g. TensorBoard). Mathematica is powerful, but not so much specialised in this kind of tasks.